# Positioning my menu bar opposite to my logo

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to take my menu bar opposite to my logo. I have tried coding in a position of relative in CSS but it's just there not repositioned

Tried typing in a position of relative in my CSS code of my html index. What can I do

Comment: You should add your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Flexbox with `justify-content: space-between` is probably your best friend!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My thought was exactly as tacoshy [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76572702/positioning-my-menu-bar-opposite-to-my-logo#comment135008029_76572702) of using Flexbox with `justify-content: space-between` but I'll go ahead and show an example.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#somwhere">Portal</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```